# SAGAN - is there a mistake in the original paper?

Tags: deep-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, image-processing, attention, attn-gan

in the original paper the following scheme of the self-attention appears:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08318.pdf
[image]

In a later overview:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01529.pdf

this scheme appears:
[image]
referring the original paper.

My understanding more correlates with the second paper scheme, as:
[image]
Where there is two dot-product operations and three hidden parametric matrices:
$$W_k, W_v, W_q$$
which corresponds to $W_f, W_g, W_h$ without $W_v$ as it in the original paper explanation, which is as following:

[image]

Is this a mistake in the original paper ?

Comment: I don't understand where the mistake is. Can you please clarify where the mistake is?

Comment: I think I was confused by the notation of v as a vector function, I thought it is a vector and then it didn't work out. So eventually there is non.